# XAML DataGrid Checkbox Column Header Not Visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

I have a datagrid in XAML.  The first column contains checkboxes for each row.
I want to have a checkbox in the header row too.  I tried to define one, but it isn't displaying.  In the XAML Window editor, when I select the checkbox element for the header I see an outline of where it should be, but it is hidden.
It looks like it may not be on top of the grid.
How can I make the header checkbox visible?

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredCheckStyle}" Width="41" 
 CellStyle="{StaticResource SingleClickEditing}"  Visibility="{Binding exists}"
 Binding="{Binding Path=toTransfer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" 
 CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="false" CanUserReorder="false">
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    IsThreeState="False" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Here is the definition of the CenteredCheckStyle

```
<Style  x:Key="CenteredCheckStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Remove the `StackPanel` since it's redundant. Also remove the Margin on Checkbox and maybe make its alignment center and see if you see it then. Nothing stands out as a cause to not see it specifically so I'll assume it's possibly just the alignment and margin pushing it around out of view.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help.  I removed the StackPanel, changed HorizontalAlignment to Center.  When selected in the editor I see the rectangle outline of where it should be, so it seems to be positioned correctly.  The checkboxes in the rows of the grid display correctly.

Comment: Out of curiosity what about removing that fixed Width? Something has to be pushing that thing out of the contentpresenter's viewport somewhere. I wouldn't expect that elementstyle or cellstyle to do it but to eliminate possibilities might try without them also. If I find time in a bit I'll try to run your stuff and see if I see the same result.

Comment: You're right. I found the problem.  To make the grid resizable, another column had Width="*"  and then I changed the Width="41" to MinWidth="41".  Thanks